# Single or multiple repositories ? : project with parts in Visual Studio, Eclipse, SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, eclipse, git, visual-studio-2012

I'm starting a project which consists of multiple parts :
- Android client developed in Java in Eclipse
- Windows client developed in C# in Visual Studio
- ServerCode (WCF service) developed in C# in Visual Studio
- Database scripts & stored procedures in SQL Server Management Studio

I would like to use GIT as version control for this multi-language, multi-IDE project.

Is it advisable to create a seperate repo for each part or should I put all parts together in a single repository ?

One of the important requirements is to be able to keep track of which version of which part is compatible with which version(s) of the other parts.

Looking forward to your advice and experiences with the use of GIT for this type of complex projects.

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

You're allowed to use multiple repositories. A hood technique is to TAG milestone releases of your projects, giving then a "version number", and then manage dependencies with maven or a similar tool (a bit more sophisticated than Ant)

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html